# Ubuntu running slow

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a local disk of 20 GB. Ubuntu is running slow and too often freeze for a few seconds. I checked RAM and CPU usage and it is normal. May be that is installed on a low space local disk?Or what else?

Comment: What is the make/model of the computer, its specs (CPU, Graphics, RAM etc), what have you tried... Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/497807/edit) your question and add more information to it.

Comment: Could be most anything, I've seen wireless cards do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is 20gb then it has probably run out of space, having no room in the root drive can crash it pretty easily

Comment: then how can i solve this? can i add memory from another local disk?

Comment: if the hard drive itself is 20gb then I really think it's time to upgrade, as using anything that isn't text based on that will be a pain for keeping from filling up, but if you really need to use that disk as root, but have other disks installed, have it mount another disk/partition as home in a fresh installation

Comment: there is a 500GB HDD and I parted 20GB from it from linux, i can add more memory to this local disk right?do i really need to reinstall linux?

Comment: if you can resize the other partition(s) on the disk then resize ubuntu to be at the VERY LEAST 40gb, I usually use 80-120 because I  use it as my main OS

Comment: I will try to resize, thnk you very much for you fast and usefull respond

Comment: when resizing try and make sure everything else is closed and that the partition is not mounted, just to make as little margin for error as possible

Comment: it seems that i can't resize it, but can i manage flags or something to make it run from a bigger local disk that i have?

Comment: you can't resize it from within it, you need to boot into a livecd as it is the root volume while booted into it